# Populate GridViewComboBoxColumn based on another GridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have two DataGridViewComboBoxColumns, one for Items and the other for the quantity types of the item ; (Ton, Kg, Meter, etc) of the selected item.

I want the second DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to be populated with the quantity Type for the selected item in the first Combo box.

This works fine with a strange problem; when I choose an Item from the first combo box, its quantities will be populated fine, and I could choose the required quantity type. But, when I move to the next row to add another item; I choose the item and when choosing its quantity type, the previous selected quantity will disappear. I am stuck on this problem since three days, can you please help. Following is my code, I am using EditingControlShowing and SelectionChangeCommitted events.

```
    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
        //{
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.Control is ComboBox)
            {
                cbxItemCode = e.Control as ComboBox;

                cbxItemCode.SelectionChangeCommitted -= new EventHandler(cbxItemCode_SelectionChangeCommitted);
                cbxItemCode.SelectionChangeCommitted += new EventHandler(cbxItemCode_SelectionChangeCommitted);
            } else
        {
            cbxItemCode.SelectionChangeCommitted -= new EventHandler(cbxItemCode_SelectionChangeCommitted);
        }
   }
```

and this is SelectionChangeCommitted code:

```
    private void cbxItemCode_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cmbBox = (ComboBox)sender;
        if (cmbBox != null)
        {
            int intValue = Convert.ToInt16(cmbBox.SelectedValue);
            populateQuantyDescColumn(intValue);
        }
    }
```

SelectionChangeCommitted event will call populateQuantityDescColumn(intValue), passing it the item code:

```
    public void populateQuantyDescColumn(int ItmsID)
    {
        if (!(con.State == ConnectionState.Open))
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        MySqlCommand sc = new MySqlCommand("select qty.id, qty.Ar_Desc from minierp_db.itemquantity as iq, " +
                                           " minierp_db.quantity as qty, minierp_db.items as it " +
                                           " where it.id = iq.items_id and qty.id = iq.quantity_id and " +
                                           " it.id = " + ItmsID, con);
        MySqlDataReader reader;

        try
        {
            reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //dt.Clear();

            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Ar_Desc", typeof(string));
            dt.Load(reader);

            qty_desc.ValueMember = "id";
            qty_desc.DisplayMember = "ar_desc";
            qty_desc.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception - populateQuantyDescColumn(): " + e.Message + e.Source);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    } //populateQuantyDescColumn
```

any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: By "the previous selected quantity will disappear" , what do you mean ? How you are checking it ? How do you come to know that it is dis-appearing ?

Comment: When I move to the next row to select another item, the previous selection of quantity type combo box will disappear ..

Comment: You have posted everything except the XAML code.

Comment: for instance, I have two combo boxes, let's say one for Countries and one for Cities. The cities combo box must be populated according to the selected country. When I choose a country from the first combo box, the second combo box of cities will be populated accordingly. Once I selected a city for  a given country, and I moved to next row to add another country, when I choose a city for the newly added country, the previous selected city will disappear.